# How to place Build Monitor View in a specific folder

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I've managed to create a Build Monitor for my builds with DSL plugin

```
buildMonitorView('master') {
    description('All jobs for master branches')
    recurse(true)
    jobs {
        name('master')
        regex('.*(master)$')
    }
}
```

but when I try to put them into a folder

```
folder('folderName')

buildMonitorView('folderName/master') {
    description('All jobs for master branches')
    recurse(true)
    jobs {
        name('master')
        regex('parcel-delivery.*(master)$')
    }
}
```

it doesn't show anywhere. Any suggestions?

I'm creating the folder in only one place (not recreating it anywhere).

Comment: This works for me. The view shows up in the view tab bar of the folder.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I actually moved the code for folder creation `folder('folderName')` to another file that was executed later (it looks like they're processed alphabetically).

When configuring the build monitor (or I guess any other view) make sure that the folder is created only once and it's done before the view creation.