# Can I display the project-name without folder-name when using Jenkins' build-monitor-plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In our Org we have a jenksins-folder with ~15 of projects, which we want to display on a wall-monitor using build-monitor-plugin [1]. The folder-name is not important for the display, but it is repeated for every job and takes up a lot of screen-space, since Jenkins' build-monitor-plugin shows the full project name in a very big font and the foldername is kinda long (>15characters).

Is there a way to remove the folder-name from the big displayname and only show the actual name of the project?

- can I configure the plugin (or jenkins?) to somehow do what I want?
- could I achieve this with something like a greasmonkey script (could you provide some pointers? e.g. which method could I overwrite to shorten the name? Could I do it via CSS?)
- I guess forking the plugin would be an option. Any pointers to get me started?
- are there other options?

[1] https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-monitor-plugin/

---

related issues

- there is a issue, which talks about something similar, but they don't seem to use the build-monitor-plugin https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-25164
- here someone is doing something similar, but I don't understand at all where they put their config. I was using the GUI to setup my plugin, but they somehow did it in groovy? would that be an option that could work for me?  [How to place Build Monitor View in a specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129874/how-to-place-build-monitor-view-in-a-specific-folder)
- here is an open task, that maybe could solve my isuee, but I don't think it will be done anytime soon (it's open since 2015) https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-30660